# Usar mais de uma função na rota do Método Get com Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, express.js, rotas

Boa noite, eu estou começando a aprender sobre node e react.js e estou com um problema, pois preciso utilizar mais de uma função na mesma rota e pelo metodo get. Fiz o código abaixo, está funcionando, mas não sei se é uma maneira certa de fazer. gostaria de saber se tem outra maneira menos verbosa. No caso, eu usei essas duas querys pra mostrar que eu preciso usar mais de uma função por rota no metodo Get. Os select não vão ficar assim, foi so um exemplo

```
module.exports = {
    async listar(request, response)  {
        const ano = request.body;
        const mes = request.body;

        const valor = {mensal:0,
                       anual:0};

        valor.mensal = await connection('entrada')
            .sum('valor_entrada')
            .whereRaw(`Year(data_entrada) = ${ano}`)



        valor.anual = await connection('entrada')
            .sum('valor_entrada')
            .whereRaw(`Month(data_entrada) = ${mes}`)

    return response.json(valor)


}
}
```

Aqui está minha rota

```
const express = require('express');
const connection = require('./database/connection');
const EntradaController = require('./controllers/EntradaController');

const routes = express.Router();

routes.get('/entradas', EntradaController.listar);

module.exports = routes;
```

Comment: Daria pra fazer essas operações em um `SELECT` só, além de que o seu código está suscetível à injeção de SQL ali naquele `whereRaw`...

Answer (score 0):

Bom amigo , vou te dar algumas dicas , espero que ajude em relação a verbosidade do código, por se tratar de uma query na mesma tabela porem com condições diferentes, pode ser que um raw com um **SELECT** direto funcione mais acho também que não é a melhor saída.

```
  module.exports = {
    async listar(request, response)  {
      const { ano, mes }  = request.body; // Desestruturação

        // Para as funções startOfYear e endOfYear use a lib date-fns
        const inicioAno = startOfYear(new Date(`${ano}-01-01`))
        const fimAno = endOfYear(new Date(`${ano}-01-01`))

        const mensal = await connection('entrada')
          .sum('valor_entrada')
          .whereBetween('data_entrada', [formattedStartYear, formattedEndYear])

        const anual = await connection('entrada')
          .sum('valor_entrada')
          .whereRaw(`Month(data_entrada) = ${mes}`) // Aqui voce está pegando todo os meses de todos os ano. Ex: 01/2020, 01/2019 .... Ai teria que procurar uma forma melhor por causa de um SQL Injection, se for do mesmo ano que vem no request ai é so fazer o que fiz acima para os meses

        const valor = {
          mensal,
          anual
        }

      return response.json(valor)
    }
  }
```